# Building Linux from Scratch stuck, incompatible sed version?

Tags: sed, linux-kernel, lfs

I am trying to build Linux from Scratch per [LFS website](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/downloads/stable/LFS-BOOK-7.3-NOCHUNKS.html)

While I was able to install all the packages until 6.7.1 without any error, I am stuck at Installation of Linux API headers (This is after I chroot into the installation) with the error,

```
/bin/sh: /tools/bin/sed: No such file or directory
```

Now I checked if, the file exists and I found it does.

```
ls -all /tools/bin/sed
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 260350 Aug  7 20:27 /tools/bin/sed
```

exists in the installation, and I found it does.

If I try executing sed, I get the error.

```
/bin/sh: /tools/bin/sed: No such file or directory
```

Trying to find the type of file sed is, I get

```
file /tools/bin/sed
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24
```

I notice that the for part in sed is different from other files in /tools/bin 
which have **for GNU/Linux 2.6.25**

What am I missing here?

Comment: I have seen similar problems before with other tools, not specifically `sed`.
It turns out that `/bin/sh` itself is the problem. It may be a symlink to a missing file or something...
try `file /bin/sh` and try to replace it with a link for `/bin/bash`

Comment: If you exit the chroot, can you use it as normal?

Comment: This usually means that there is a linked library missing. Check the output of `ldd /tools/bin/sed`.

Comment: Possibly wrong path to the dynamic linker in that `sed` file?

Comment: @kevin, As normal user, I can use sed from the installation.

Comment: @jordanm : ldd /tools/bin/sed
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff914be000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2842798000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2842b71000)

This is what I get, my guess is I am missing the symlink for the last file ?

Answer (score 0):

@Bichoy: You were right, the problem was with bash, 
My /bin/sh was a symlink to dash instead of /bin/bash

Changed shell and I am all set to proceed with building linux.